# how to remove particluar javascript in comparision page on magento

Tags: magento-1.9, comparison

I need to remove particular JavaScript from Footer in comparison page in Magento, because its getting appearance issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d){
var app = d.createElement('script'); 
app.type = 'text/javascript'; 
app.async = true;
var pt = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://');
app.src = pt + 'www.speakpipe.com/loader/7ke3tuki7asftw30o770pky260kt5jpu.js';
var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(app, s);
})(document);
</script>
```

[image: Comparison page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove css via below code
add this code in your layout file or your theme local.xml file

```
<catalog_product_compare_index> <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/your.css</name></action></catalog_product_compare_index>
```

Or add Code like below

```
<?php if( ! in_array('catalog_product_compare_index', $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles() )):?> your js code  <?php endif; ?>
```

Above code exclude js from compare js

Comment: i need to remove script from particular page

Comment: `<catalog_product_compare_index>` this is the handler for compare page so if write remove in this tab then it will remove from compare page only

Comment: how can i remove this "<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d){
var app = d.createElement('script'); 
app.type = 'text/javascript'; 
app.async = true;
var pt = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://');
app.src = pt + 'www.speakpipe.com/loader/example.js';
var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(app, s);
})(document);
</script> "  from one page

Comment: See My updated Answer

Comment: where i want put this php code

Comment: where the Js file is . Is your js in phtml file or in seprate js File?

Comment: i am added above script in Miscellaneous HTML in config/design on admin panel

Comment: Remove js from there and add your head.phtml file in between php tag

Comment: i tried this method , but its not working

Comment: Have you get error or what?

Comment: i cant remove send voice email panel in above image

Comment: remove from backend and add only at head.phtml or footer.phtml